# Jboss 7 own authenticator

Tags: authentication, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6, authenticator

I am trying to write own authenticator which will read particular custom cookies and authenticate user based od token which is stored in that cookie. As an example I took this class: org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator

So I start to writing my own authenticator:

public class SampleAuthenticator extends AuthenticatorBase{

```
@Override
protected boolean authenticate(Request arg0, Response arg1, LoginConfig arg2) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("===CHECK===");
    return false;
}
```

As you can see my class contains only needed method that must be implemented with default values.

I have installed this authenticator as module in Jboss "modules" directory.

Then I have added new security-domain in standalone.xml:

```
<security-domain name="sso" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required" />
                </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

I have made my module as global in standalone.xml as well (in jboss domain subsystem):

```
<global-modules>
            <module name="com.myexample.authenticator"/>
</global-modules>
```

Now it seems that my authenticator is ready for use (just for output word "===CHECK===")

Into my example web application I have added jboss-web.xml descriptor:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>sso</security-domain>
    <valve>
        <class-name>com.myexample.authenticator.SampleAuthenticator</class-name>
    </valve>
</jboss-web>
```

My web.xml descriptor is following:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MyResourceName</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>My kinda secure web application</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Finally when I am trying to deploy my web application it is throwing this exception:

```
12:41:28,554 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.valve.myvalve: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.valve.myvalve: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myexample.authenticator.SampleAuthenticator cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.Valve
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebValveService.start(WebValveService.java:92)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myexample.authenticator.SampleAuthenticator cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.Valve
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebValveService.start(WebValveService.java:72)
        ... 5 more
```

I am stuck at this point. I tried to reimplement some authenticators but this ClassCastException is always there.

Can anybody help me with writing own authenticator?
I am using Jboss EAP 6.2 with Jboss 7.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using wrong lib. Problem was solved by using this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-web</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the classpath, but has repeatedly deploy your classes.

If you have already defined in the JBoss module with the autenticator, should not have this class in the war or ear